# Does $\forall(S) [S\subseteq S$ ] generate an infinite chain of subsets? If yes, is this a problem?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

In a discussion I've  had recently regarding basic notions of set theory, my interlocutor pointed out what seemed to him a " regression ad infinitum".

His point was related to the fact that any set is a subset of itself. Say we consider the set $S=\{a,b\}$.

One of $S$'s subsets is $S$ itself : $S\in P(S) = \{ \emptyset, \{a\} , \{a\} , S\}$   And $S$ as subset of itself still has $S$ has subset.

It seems to generate an infinite descending  chain of subsets.

Hence two questions :
(1) is there actually an infinite chain of subsets?
(2) in case there is such a chain, does it pose any problem?

Or, to ask my question differently : suppose you represent the subset relation by a diagram , starting at bottom with the empty set , included in singetons $\{a\}$ and $\{b\}$, which in turn are included in $S$. At the end of the diagram there is an arrow from S to itself ( due to the reflexivity of the subset relation ). *Is the whole diagram " duplicated" at its top*, indefinitely?

At first I suspected the " objection " arose from a confusion between inclusion and membership relation . But I'm not sure it is the case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The confusion, as you suspected, is between $\in$ and $\subseteq$. The axiom of foundation states that no set satisfies $x\in x$. Is such a set was allowed, then it would lead to an infinite membership chain $\dots \in x\in x\in x\in x\dots $. Set inclusion, on the other hand, always satisfies $x\subseteq x$ simply since it states that every member of $x$ is a member of $x$ --- clearly true. On this note one should mention that sets that do satisfy $x\in x$ are studied. This is known as non well-founded set theory.

Answer (score 1):

Similarly, what's wrong with $1 \le 1 \le 1 \le \dots$ (or where $\le$ is replaced by $\ge$)? If you're happy with this, then you should be happy with the sets.

Answer (score 0):

> One of $S$'s subsets is $S$ itself $[\dots]$ and $S$ as subset of itself still has $S$ as subset.

You just repeated it twice.

Comment: hence the appearence of " regression ad infinitum" ...

Comment: There is no chain in saying for example $S \cup S \cup S \cup \dots \cup S$. It is always the same set